# Terminal Services: Get Client Name While Running As Administrator

Tags: vb.net, environment-variables, terminal-services

Under normal circumstances, a VB.NET application of mine can check the ClientName environmental variable to get the name of the workstation the user is connecting from.

So when WorkstationX RDPs into ServerA:

- ComputerName=ServerA
- ClientName=WorkstationX

That works fine.

If I right-click on the application and choose Run As Administrator, the ClientName variable is not set.

Does anyone know of a way of easily getting the workstation name of the client connected to the terminal server, even when the application is launched via "Run As Administrator"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [terminal services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383468(VS.85).aspx) might be your answer. I use it in a VB.NET app to log off user sessions on a given server, and to retrieve the names of the workstations connected to those sessions. The code I have has a lot of p-invoke stuff and is rather unwieldy, but I can post it if you want.

Comment: I assumed I would need to use WTSQuerySessionInformation to get to the value of WTSClientName, but haven't found any clean examples of doing so yet.

Comment: Clean as in working and minimal use of sketchy calls using ported VB6 code ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to deal with the P/Invoke business yourself, you can use [Cassia](http://cassia.googlecode.com/), which wraps it for you:

```
New Cassia.TerminalServicesManager().CurrentSession.ClientName
```

Comment: I installed a Cassia NuGet package and it is (still) much more reliable at returning the client name that the CLIENTNAME environment variable.